# How to programmatically reload Cordova Plugins after app crash?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crash, cordova-plugins

There are times when my Ionic V1 w Cordova App crashes and then immediately restarts in iOS. While I'd prefer it never crash, at the moment I'm working on making sure it recovers properly. The problem is that when it restarts the app the Ionic code is initialized and run properly but none of the Cordova plugins are available.

Is it possible to programmatically reload all the Cordova plugins on startup from the Ionic app?

Comment: You are trying to address an issue casued by a primary issue. Solve the main bug, this will get resolved.

Comment: Yes, we are trying to address or at least minimize the occurrence of the primary issue. However, because various scenarios, including unknown scenarios, could cause it, I also want to make sure the app recovers better if it does happen to crash. When I drive a car I do my best to avoid accidents but I also always wear a seat belt just in case. I'm trying to create a seat belt here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the

> crashes and then immediately restarts in iOS

part happens, but have you tried to use `location.reload()`?

For instance, in `index.html`

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  //...
  location.reload();
  return;
}
```

It might do the trick, although I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks that works and I just figured out that so does `document.location.href = 'index.html';`, which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

document.location.href = 'index.html';

best solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).